# Small laravel 4 project versioning with git

Tags: php, git, version-control, laravel, bitbucket

I've been trying to wrap my head around the different parts of git, but am having a little trouble. The use case is a small project, and only I will be the developer (maybe someone else will help in the future, who knows).

I develop on my local machine, I push the code to a repository like bitbucket, and I'd like to pull that code down (or have it happen automatically) on my production environment hosted on a linux server. What are the necessary steps to make this happen? I'm open to other configurations if it makes sense, but I want to keep it simple and scalable.

I've gotten as far as committing code locally, and pushing to the repository (successfully). Now I'd like to merge that code in whatever is the most efficient way.

There is probably a very simple solution, but I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to keep it simple and scalable, the easiest way to get started is to look to automatic deployments using Git hooks (for example - post-merge hook).  I don't have much experience with BitBucket, but below are a few good resources I found that might get you pointed in the right direction:

- Plain Git: http://12devsofxmas.co.uk/2013/01/day-9-deploy-your-projects-with-git/
- BitBucket: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using Laravel 4.1, you could use the Rocketeer packagage (https://github.com/Anahkiasen/rocketeer) to deploy directly to your server.

For the past couple of years I've been using http://www.beanstalkapp.com. It has a git repository and deployment servers - so once you push your code you can deploy (using FTP or SSH) directly to your server. It also has deployment rollback, so if your deployment fails, you can quickly revert to a previous release. I think it has a free option, so worth a look.

Thirdly, you could try Capistrano. It's a bit like Rocketeer, but needs a little more configuration. There are tutorials on Youtube and around the web.

Good luck!